# Entity Framework Core where clause extra condiition

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this simple query, the problem is that the `End` property is `DateTime?` type and I would like to include the records where this value is null as well but I cannot seem to do it. I tried using the Terniary operator and still no results

```
await _context.Registos
    .Where(r => r.Start.Date >= DateStart.Date && r.End.HasValue ? r.End.Value <= DateEnd.Date : !r.End.HasValue )
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner way, something like this:

```
await _context.Registos
    .Where(r => r.Start.Date >= DateStart.Date 
        && (r.End == null || r.End.Value <= DateEnd.Date))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await _context.Registos
    .Where(r => r.Start.Date >= DateStart.Date && 
              (!r.End.HasValue || (r.End.Value <= DateEnd.Date)) )
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way of having a variable that hasn't been assigned a value in C# is for it to be a local variable - in which case at compile-time you can tell that it isn't assigned by trying to read from it :)

I suspect you want `Nullable<DateTime>` (or DateTime? with the C# syntactic sugar) - make it null to start with and then assign a normal DateTime value (which will be converted appropriately). Then you can just compare with null (or use the HasValue property) to see whether a "real" value has been set.